# How to put a box around a single page?

Tags: pdftex, box, nomencl

I used `nomencl` and created a page of nomenclatures in my paper, I want to put this page and this page only into a box, while everything else are to remain the same.

I tried the following code I found online but it puts a watermark of "draft" on the first page (before my nomenclature page) and boxed every page after that.

```
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=4pt,]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (2cm,-2cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-2cm,2cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Does anyone have a better solution?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## `\AddToHook{shipout/background}`

We can draw the frame using tikz and add to background using `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{...some code...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{
\begin{tikz}[remember picture, overlay,shift=(current page.north west)]
\draw[rounded corners=4pt, line width = 1pt, black] (2cm,-2cm) -- (2cm,2cm-\paperheight) -- (\paperwidth-2cm, 2cm-\paperheight) -- (\paperwidth-2cm,-2cm)--cycle;
\end{tikz}
}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage

\RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}
\lipsum[1]
\nomenclature[a]{$E$}{Energy}
\nomenclature[a]{$m$}{Mass}
\nomenclature[a]{$c$}{Speed of Light}
\[E=m\cdot c^2 \]

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

## Using the `background` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{background}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=4pt,]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (2cm,-2cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-2cm,2cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage

\AddToHook{shipout/before}{
\NoBgThispage
}

\lipsum[1]
\nomenclature[a]{$E$}{Energy}
\nomenclature[a]{$m$}{Mass}
\nomenclature[a]{$c$}{Speed of Light}

\[E=m\cdot c^2 \]

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The reason you get the watermark "draft" on your first page is because the `backgound` package set background for every page by default. And you put the `\SetBgContents{}` command locally in your document. So the pages before \SetBgContents{} have been defined will use the default background figure which is big red color slanted text "draft" in the center of the page. You need explicit set `\NoBgThispage` in order to make a particular page without background. That is why I add `\AddToHook{shipout/before}{\NoBgThispage}` to set the rest of the pages without the box frame.